# Facebook link creating whitespace in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm using Facebook's own script, and have implemented that on my site.
The problem is that it makes a whitespace of about 35px * the page height at the right side of the site. I cannot find it anywhere in firebug, and have isolated the script to be the cause.

How can I use it, or change it so I don't get that whitespace? really annoying to get a horizontal scroll because of this!
if I set a width to the fb:like that is over 400px(the div size) the whitespace disappears but the button is placed wrong

Script:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=222642751115062&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<My Page Name>" send="true" width="350" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

Screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/problemx.png/

**CURRENT SOLUTION**
Put the background-image on body tag to get it to make the whitespace be the same color as background, then removing scrollbars like this:

```
html
{
overflow-x: hidden ! important;
overflow-y: auto ! important;   
}
```

Comment: I can't view your screenshot.  Do you have a live link to the page, perhaps?  Basically, facebook inserts an iframe into your page.  This messes up a ton of flow around the page, but it shouldn't induce any problems outside of what the iFrame itself consumes.  Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/problemx.png/

Answer (score 1):

I think the with of the like button is simply to wide. Try setting it to a lower value `(width="150")`:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=222642751115062&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<My Page Name>" send="true" width="150" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: Tried that, and nothing happens! if i set a width to the fb:like that is over 400px(the div size) the whitespace dissappears but the button is placed wrong